# How to increase space/indentation of lists like labels and enumerations in LyX?

Tags: spacing, lyx, indentation

When I use a label, it leaves a default space between the label and the following text.

I want to increase this *horizontal* space/indentation by a lot more in LyX, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Just to clarify, I'd really like to do this on LyX and not LaTeX.

Comment: So you're talking about the LyX interface, not the LaTeX output, correct?

Comment: That's right. I'm wondering if there's something I could stick into the preamble to establish the indent space throughout the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjusting anything with regards to the `lyxlist` environment *globally* would have to be done using a Document > Settings... > Local Layout. The following layout was copied verbatim from `stdlyxlist.inc`:

```
Format 49

Style Labeling
  Category              List
  Margin                Manual
  LatexType             List_Environment
  LatexName             lyxlist
  NextNoindent          1
  LabelSep              xxx
  ParSkip               0.4
  TopSep                0.7
  BottomSep             0.7
  ParSep                0.5
  Align                 Block
  AlignPossible         Block, Left
  LabelType             Manual
  LabelString           "00.00.0000"
  HTMLTag               ol
  HTMLAttr              class='lyxlist'
  HTMLItem              li
  HTMLLabel             span
  HTMLLabelAttr         class='lyxlist'

  #define the environment lyxlist
  Preamble
    \newenvironment{lyxlist}[1]
      {\begin{list}{}
        {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}
         \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}
         \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
         \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hfil}}}
      {\end{list}}
  EndPreamble

  HTMLStyle
    ol.lyxlist {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    li.labeling_item {
      text-indent: -5em;
      margin-left: 5em;
    }
    span.lyxlist {
      margin-right: 1em;
    }
  EndHTMLStyle
End
```

Note the `LabelString` set to `00.00.0000` by default. Change this to any string that would be long enough to suit your needs and you'll see the corresponding `Labeling` lists in LyX change their so-called "label sep". You may have to temporarily switch the list to something else and back again in order to see the effect.

The above changes things on the LyX side (in the display). For a global change on LaTeX's side, you'll have to add content to the `lyxlist` environment definition. For example:

```
  #define the environment lyxlist
  Preamble
    \newenvironment{lyxlist}[1]
      {\begin{list}{}
        {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}
         \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}
         \setlength{\labelsep}{5em}% Change this to suit your needs
         \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
         \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hfil}}}
      {\end{list}}
  EndPreamble
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is half a solution. Right clicking somewhere in the labeling environment and changing the Paragraph Settings... > Label Width > Longest Label value to the longest word you are using does the trick, but it isn't a global solution.

EDIT: The LyX version I am using is 2.1.2.

Comment: What version of LyX is this?

Comment: It is Lyx 2.1.2.

Comment: Works very well in lyx 2.2.0. I can't think of a reason I would want it to be a global solution. Each list could have whatever spacing looks best. It doesn't even seem to me that the original question was asking for a global solution.

Comment: Note this works only for `list` paragraphs (`Alt PN`). not for `description` paragraphs, and as you wrote, the value to enter is the longest word itself, not the length of the longest word. Your solution is correct, a global setting doesn't make sense.